# I can't run steam and I think my nvidia driver is the problem

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, steam

I have read many, many posts and guides about how to do this, and I am just getting frustrated. I've reinstalled the xubuntu 12.04 half a dozen times. What I would like to do is play games with steam. I am able to get xubuntu to boot, but I can't get into steam. It gives me a variety of errors based on the nvidia driver I install. When I use nvidia-331, my system boots to tty1 and I have to purge nvidia and start over. The other nvidia drivers give me errors on loading steam like "openGL GLX extension not supported by display." I was able to play my entire library on windows xp, but now I want to give linux a try since xp is no longer supported.

edit: I am running a laptop with an nvidia 8600m gt.

Comment: Anybody here willing/able to help?